# C# SetParent and Modal on different executables

Tags: c#, winapi, modal-dialog

I have two executables in C#, lets call them executable A and B, both of them have one form. Executable A gets the MainWindowHandle of B and then calls SetParent(this.Handle, B.MainWindowHandle). How can I set the form of executable B to be a Modal so that the form of executable A wont receive input unless I close the form B. Something like when you do frm.ShowDialog().
Thank you very much.

Comment: Is B.ShowDialog() not working then?

Comment: Its not because form B is on a different executable (executable B), and I need a Win32 Api (probably) method of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, given AForm and BForm, I've created a test project which references another Winforms project (which contains BForm), and I can do this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var bForm = new WindowsFormApplication2.BForm();
  bForm.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

With or without passing in an IWin32Window owner property to the ShowDialog function, mine correctly forces modal on my BForm.

Can you show us some code?

Comment: I have to be more precise, while the above solution is perfect I will need to do it with Win32 API because the executable B might be a C++ or Visual Basic 6 program so I wont be able to call ShowDialog() with a C++ (for example) executable.